# repeat laravel query result 4 times

Tags: laravel-5

i have a question on how to accomplish this task..

how can i repeat the result of a query 4 times and then add a name from other database.. please check this attach image.

[image]

i have a database for flight number. and a database for employee name.

this is my code so far

```
 @foreach ( $daily_flight as $d_f)
           {{ $d_f->flight_num}}
  @endforeach




   <table>
     @foreach ($csa as $emp)
          <tr>
             <td>{{ $emp->name }}</td>
          </tr>
     @endforeach
     </table>
```

Comment: By database you mean table?

Comment: @Poiz Let's hope so

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that you have 2 tables: **flights** and **employees**. Let us also imagine that the `flights` Table has `columns` like `id`, `flight_num`, `etc`. Simultaneously; we would also assume that the `employees` Table contain fields like: `id`, `flight_id`, `name`, etc. Now, working under this arbitrary condition, one can ***simply write a Query that joins the 2 tables*** provided there is any kind of `JoinCondition` that can be established between the 2 - for example: `ON employees.flight_id=flights.id`.

This would be how to do this from the Controller:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\User;
    use App\Flights;        //<== JUST SOME ARBITRARY IMPORTS... MODIFY TO SUIT YOU
    use App\Employees;      //<== JUST SOME ARBITRARY IMPORTS... MODIFY TO SUIT YOU
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;


    class FlightsController extends Controller {


        public function flightSchedule(){     //<== ANOTHER ARBITRARY ACTION METHOD
            // ASSUME FOR AN INSTANT THAT YOU HAVE 2 TABLES:
            // 1.) flights
            // 2.) employees
            // YOU COULD USE THE join CLAUSE TO JOIN THE 2 TABLES TOGETHER
            $flightData = DB::table('flights')
                       ->join('employees', 'employees.flight_id', '=', 'flights.id')
                       ->select('flights.*', 'employee.*')
                       ->groupBy('employees.name')
                       ->get();

            // THEN ONCE YOU HAVE YOUR RESULT, IT WOULD BE ONLY
            // A MATTER OF LOOPING THROUGH THE RESULT-SET IN THE VIEW SCRIPT
            // AND STRUCTURING YOUR MARK-UP AS YOU SEE FIT LIKE THIS:

            return view("flights.schedule", array("flightData"=>$flightData));
        }

    }
```

Now, in your View Script in our Arbitrary Example; `flights/schedule.blade.php`

```
    <!-- FICTITIOUS FILE-NAME=> flights/schedule.blade.php -->

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>FLIGHT NUMBER</th>
            <th>ASSIGNED EMPLOYEE</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($flightData as $data)
                 <tr>
                     <td>{{ $data->flight_num }}</td>
                     <td>{{ $data->name }}</td>
                 </tr>
            @endforeach;
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: hello thank you for your explanation and answer. basically the logic i need is. Foreach FLIGHT NUMBER i need 4 EMPLOYEES.   yes i have flight table and employees table. so first ill show all the flight number and then assigned 4 employees each